# Building a heroku docker image for a specific context

Tags: docker, heroku

When using `heroku.yml` developer preview (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml). Is there currently any way of specifying a docker build context as well as the dockerfile?

The command I'd like to emulate is:

```
docker build -f cmd/api/Dockerfile .
```

> **Note:** I provide the path `.` for the build context here.

Currently, I'm able to successfully run the following:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: cmd/api/Dockerfile
```

Or, using the more explicit version:

```
build:
  docker:
    web:
      dockerfile: cmd/api/Dockerfile
```

Based on the ability to [target a stage from a multi-stage build](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#targeting-a-stage-from-a-multi-stage-build), my assumption was that I would also be able to provide `context` in the same way I would `docker-compose` as a field for the build:

```
build:
  docker:
    web:
      dockerfile: cmd/api/Dockerfile
      context: .
```

However, this returns the following error response from Heroku:

```
remote: Building source:
remote: === Fetching app code
remote:
remote: =!= There were problems parsing your heroku.yml. We've detected the following issues:
remote:
remote: build.docker.web.context in body is a forbidden property
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to docker-build-context-test.
remote:
```

Is this a known feature that I can implement? It's very possible I might need to send in a feature request, as this functionality is a developer preview, but it feels like something they would've included.

Hope you guys have some answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml

> The Docker build context is always set to the directory containing the Dockerfile and cannot be configured independently.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting this earlier. I think I solved this a few hours later by finding the same documentation link, and totally forgot about it. Thanks for your help though, hope it can save someone else a headache!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, using a symbolic link to your Dockerfile works:

```
ln -s  path/to/your/Dockerfile Dockerfile.heroku
```

with

```
build:
  docker:
    web:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.heroku
```